# Defining HTML attributes with template string

Tags: javascript, html, template-strings

I am trying to set the href attribute of an `<a>`-Tag inside a template string but it does not work.

```
function createLink(object) {
return `<a href="${object.DetailActionUri}">Detail</a>`;
}
```

Comment: What is `object.DetailActionUri`? And when you say it’s not working... how? We can’t read your mind.

Comment: This is form a TYPO3 extension and object.DetailActionUri contains the Uri to an action which i created in the Controller and gave it as a property to my object. 
The function "createLink" is called within the Fetch API. 

I was receiving a TYPO3 page not found error, even though the URI worked when i copied and pasted it to the URL-bar of my browser.

The problem was, that i forgot to delete some TYPO3 Viewhelpers inside the template string. After deleting them, the link works now when i am clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

The template string also contained some TYPO3 Viewhelpers, which caused that the link did not work. After deleting them, the link is working now.